# Route ashx path to ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httphandler

I have a legacy application where an `ashx` path used to go to an `HttpHandler` but I would like it to go to an `ApiController` without changing the path.

So `my.application.com/auth/gettoken.ashx` used to go to an "old-school" `ashx.cs` file, but now I want it to go to a regular WebAPI controller.

I've tried removing the handler and adding an ApiController with the correct route. This works locally, but not in production. I assume because my local IIS Express is configured differently than the production IIS.

Can I achieve this? I would be okay with disabling `ashx` handlers altogether. I've tried this in my web.config, but it didn't work:

```
<remove name="SimpleHandler"/>
```

I've looked into a redirect, but  I'm doing a `POST` to this URL, so a redirect won't seem to work either.

So, can I, in any way, have a call to a path with an `.ashx` extension be routed to a regulare WebAPI `ApiController`?

Comment: I would start by making your application run under proper IIS, not IIS Express, then when you do find a solution, you can be sure it will work in production as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've currently reintroduced the `ashx` file, as I didn't find any other solution. If someone ever does, I'd happily mark that as the accepted answer (and change my code).